# uploading image to Facebook albums not uploaded properly using Facebook-connect Android

Tags: android, image, facebook

i uploaded image to facebook using facebook SDK example.  It looks like as show below :

[image: image after uploading to facebook]
image after uploading to facebook

[image: image before uploading to facebook which is on my server]
image before uploading to facebook which is on my server

is anyone facing same problem with the image after uploading image on facebook??  If so how to solve this problem?

I am using the same code which is given in Facebook-Android Example:

```
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)uploadFileUrl.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                int length = conn.getContentLength();
                byte[] imgData =new byte[length];
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                is.read(imgData);
                params.putByteArray("picture", imgData);
```

Thanks in advance, aby

Comment: Have you looked at your logcat? Where there any exceptions, its possible the connection timedout.

Comment: everything is fine in the logcat.  when i tried the URL which i available in the example which is of FBCDN its working fine.  But when i uploaded image using my own URL its uploads the image shown above.

Comment: This might be a Facebook issue, but it might also be an issue with how your code is prepping the image to be sent. Can you share your code that reads the image (form your server) and calls the Facebook SDK?

Comment: @torid: i have posted the code please check..

Comment: One thing that strikes me is that you use getContentLength to determine the size of the imgData byte array. But the docs say that "Since getContentLength() returns the number of bytes transmitted, you cannot use that method to predict how many bytes can be read from getInputStream(). Instead, read that stream until it is exhausted: when read() returns -1." It might be helpful to check what length you get back from getContentLength and compare it to a calcualtion of bitmap size (height x width x bitperpixel / 8). It might be that you're sending the GZIPd length bytes - hence the partial image.